# python: problem importing protobuf generated files

Tags: python, python-import, protobuf-python

I'm testing files generated by protobuf for use with python. The problem that I'm hitting is that protobuf is separating the generated python files in directories and then I have problems with the imports with python2.

Say, I have directories `common` and `a`, each with autogenerated (by protobuf) py files. If you take a look at one of the files in `a`, it has an import that says:

```
from common import x_pb2 as common_dot_x__pb2
```

So, I have another script that I'm creating to import the file in `a`. So.... if I try providing the parent (of `common` and `a`) to PYTHONPATH, I can't seem to find a way to import the script in `a`:

```
from a import blah
```

(blah.py being the autogenerated py file inside `a`) I get this:

```
ImportError: No module named a
```

So.... if I try adding the `a` directory to PYTHONPATH (and adjusting the import to only say `import blah`, then I start getting a problem importing from common (import statement in autogenerated blah.py file in `a`):

```
    from common import x_pb2 as common_dot_x__pb2
ImportError: No module named common
```

What should be the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..... got a **workaround**: In all of the directories where the autogenerated files are, add an empty **init**.py file. That way imports start behaving. Does anybody know of an easier way to do it? (And no w I have to see if this can be done automagically by protoc or with maven somehow).